# How to reload a controller's angularJS call from a factory initiated by another controller

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angularJS project, a music player which can select an album and then play from a list of that album's songs. Everything is working except for that after playing a song from an album(album A) and then selecting another album (album B), when I try to select the previous/next song from a player bar, which is separated from the list, the previous album's (album A) songs play.

Clearly, something is not updating. I read [here from a comment by Chev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813232/angular-controller-needing-refresh-to-pickup-new-data-in-a-factory-promise) that factories run only once. So, I am thinking the problem might lie with my Songplayer controller(factory).

Here's the code:

AlbumController (the controller with the directive):

```
....
$rootscope.getAlbumId = $stateParams.getAlbumId;
this.albumData = Fixtures.getAlbum();
this.songPlayer = SongPlayer;
....
```

FixturesController (factory - serving the music files):

```
Fixtures.getAlbum = function(){
  var chosenAlbum = $rootScope.getAlbumId
  return chosenAlbum
....
};
```

SongPlayerController (factory - playing the music):

```
....
$rootScope.getAlbumId = $stateParams.getAlbumId;
var currentAlbum = Fixtures.getAlbum();
....
var getSongIndex = function(song){
return currentAlbum.songs.indexOf(song);
};
```

PlayerBarController:

```
code same as albumController
```

It seems the PlayerBarController is not registering the new album from the SongPlayer factory. I have researched and tried using $emit/$broadcast, $watch, various other callbacks, etc... I know the answer is everywhere I have looked but I simply do not have the angular skills yet to figure this out.

Incidentally, I figure my use of $rootScope is also pretty poor, so I am happy to receive advice on that. I used $rootscope and $stateparams in order to capture and register the album id and deliver it to the Fixtures controller.

Comment: Using `$rootScope` is ok for a small example like that.  In a larger project you probably group relevant data/methods on a custom service, inject it, and use it the same way.  `$emit` is good for an events based pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the PlayerBar controller to register the new album by using $watch. I simply wrapped the call I already had in a $watch function, and voila!

SongPlayer controller:

```
    $rootScope.$watch('getAlbumId', function(album){
     currentAlbum = Fixtures.getAlbum();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem from 'this.albumData = Fixtures.getAlbum();'
You can try:

```
let albumData = Fixtures.getAlbum();
this.albumData.length = 0;
albumData.map(item => this.albumData.push(item));
```